# Javascript converts back-slash characters into forward-slash characters

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, safari

When using Javascript to redirect the user to another page (assigning to document.location), I've noticed that Javascript will convert any back-slash character you pass into the URL into a forward-slash character.

eg, given this sample HTML document

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" id="takemeto" value="hello" onclick="document.location = '/hello\\world';" />
</body>
</html>
```

The expected URL it should attempt to load is '/hello\world', however, the URL it actually attempts to load is '/hello/world'. This problem only seems to occur in Safari as Firefox seems to correctly maintain my URL.

My question is, is there a way to perform a redirect in Javascript that is cross-browser and that will maintain the back-slash characters in my URL?

Comment: Just a point of information: `/` is a forward slash; `\\` is a backslash. You seem to have the terminology backwards. See the [Unicode Basic Latin code chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf) (particularly entries 002F and 005C).

Comment: Whoops, thanks for the catch, will correct!

Answer (score 2):

You can try [percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the character:

```
document.location = '/hello%5Cworld'
```